# Multiple jQuery includings causing fancybox to break?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, include, fancybox, multiple-instances

I'm not sure what's going on here, i'm a little bit confused.

This is the page i'm currently working on: http://tinyurl.com/a8yuzdt

When you go to the page, everything works, right? All scripts are running good! Except for the fancybox jquery plugin, it gives me the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fancybox'
```

It appears it didn't load for some reason. I have no idea why. I tried checking if jQuery was loaded correctly (perhaps the fancybox script was included before jquery or something), and found that i include *two* instances of jquery on every load. The second including is from wordpress though, i think it automatically includes jQuery.

The problem is, if i remove my own jquery inclusion, nothing works! If i run `$` in the console i get `undefined`. If i run `jQuery` i get this:

```
function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)}
```

So i guess... it's kind of working, but only if i use `jQuery` instead of `$`? Check it yourself, go to the page and search for `jquery` in the source.

Any ideas how i fix this?

Comment: where have you included jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you include jQuery, then some plugins (for example, fancyBox) and then another jQuery, then all previously loaded plugins will be lost.

Edit. I inspected your page and found that

1. The actual error message is - `TypeError: $ is not a function`
2. The reason of this is because your jQuery runs into "noConflict" mode. For some reasons, the last line of your jQuery file is - `jQuery.noConflict();`

And therefore you either have to use `jQuery` instead of `$` or remove `jQuery.noConflict();` line.

Comment: That's not the case though. Both jQuery includings are in the header (no scripts in between or above), and my scripts are included in the footer (that includes fancybox), so it should be working right? Take a look at the source, fancybox and my other scripts are inside `theme.js`.

Comment: @qwerty : you are including the fancybox init BEFORE the fancybox plugin .... move the includings to top and the inits to the bottom

Comment: Are you refering to the code inside theme.js? If so, shouldn't it work anyways, because even though the fancybox plugin code is below the init, it runs directly when the document loads (it doesn't wait for it to finish loading), unlike the init code which runs after the document has loaded. Right?

Comment: Ah, saw your edit now! Is it possible to disable the noConflict()? **Edit** The problem is wordpress is automatically loading the jquery file that has noConflict() in it, so i don't have the power of modifying it as far as i know.

Comment: According to the wordpress doc (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_wrappers) they put it in there with purpose. I tried wrapping the code in `jQuery(document).ready(function(){});` but that didn't work. Lastly, i tried just replacing all `$` symbols with `jQuery`, and now it seems to work. Downside is if there is any actual `$` symbols in the scripts (as strings), it's now replaced with jQuery. Ah, whatever, it works, thanks!

Comment: Maybe try `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {` (http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16494)